# Accessing text elements in SVG files with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg

Since I first asked this question I have made some progress.

If I create the SVG within HTML and give the text items I want to change IDs, I have no problem accessing the ID using

```
let callQSO = document.getElementById("QSOcall").value;
```

and then writing that to the SVG with

```
document.getElementById("SVGcallQSO").innerHTML = callQSO;
```

However for various reasons I want the SVG to be outside the HTML.

So I load the SVG as an object

Then try to get the elements of the object from within JS with

```
 let svgObject = document.getElementById('svg-object').contentDocument;
```

from the console I can see this returns a null.

Can anyone offer any suggestion that would mean I can read the elelments from the external svg and manipulate them?

As always, grateful for any help.

Comment: You can also rename your text elements' IDs to something more self-explanatory: this helps to make your script more readable. For instance,  if "#text3332" displays a name you could rename it to "textName" and change/update the text like so: `textName.textContent=inputName.value`. "inputName" would be the ID of the corresponding form input field populating the svg `<text>` element. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/OJByqYq).

Comment: Keep in mind, a lot of people are not familiar with svg and don't know how to display them. Besides a lot of email clients can't display svg. So you might consider to convert the card svg to a raster image like .png for email usage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the conversion to png later should not be a proble.
But as far as I understand it, there is no way of accessing elements withing a PNG.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `querySelector` and start with the `<div>` holding the embedded SVG.

```js
// Some more text
console.log(document.querySelector('.svg-wrapper #text3332').textContent.trim());

// Some text or other
console.log(document.querySelector('.svg-wrapper #text3599').textContent.trim());
```

```html
<div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg>
    <g inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="layer1" inkscape:label="text 1">
      <text xml:space="preserve" style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:16px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" x="395.71747" y="74.062111" id="text3332">
        <tspan sodipodi:role="line" id="tspan3330" x="395.71747" y="74.062111" style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:16px;font-family:Ubuntu;-inkscape-font-specification:Ubuntu">Some text or other</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
    <g inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="layer2" inkscape:label="text 2">
      <text xml:space="preserve" style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:16px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" x="395.06018" y="113.68354" id="text3599">
        <tspan sodipodi:role="line" id="tspan3597" x="395.06018" y="113.68354" style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:16px;font-family:Ubuntu;-inkscape-font-specification:Ubuntu">Some more text</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Obviously the <div class="svg-wrapper goes into the html of the page, what do I do with the first section?
I think this may be above my paygrade.

Comment: @Derek is the SVG embedded into the HTML, or is it the `src` of an `<img>` element?

Comment: I have added the image as an Object.
<object id="svg-object" data="http://www.bsears.co.uk/svg/G6BSE.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
Then from withing the JS I do this:
var svgObject = document.getElementById('svg-object').contentDocument;
To load the svg contents.
Then I try to get an element from the svgObject variable with
var svgtext1423 = svgObject.getElementById('text1423').value;   
And that line breaks the whole script, up to then I am able to get other elements from the form.
All and any help appreciated.

Comment: Polywhirl The SVG image i loaded into the html file as an object.